# 500 Internal Server Error ajax/ laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to create a dynamic comment section but this problem seems to trouble me 500 Internal Server Error. I've read a little about this problem but I couldn't fix it. I used some code snippets to find the problem but I still can't find what is t problem.

create.blade.php -

```
<h1>Create comment</h1>
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'myForm',  'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'article-ckeditor', 'placeholder' => 'Share your thoughts related to this post']) }}
</div>
{{ Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id) }}
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'submitComment'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Ajax -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitComment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/comments') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                body: $('#article-ckeditor').val(),
                post_id: $('#post_id').val()
            },
            success: function(result){
                $('.alert').show();
                $('.alert').html(result.success);
            },
           /* error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }*/
            error: function(jqXhr, json, errorThrown){// this are default for ajax errors
                var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
                var errorsHtml = '';
                $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                    errorsHtml += '<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item alert alert-danger">' + value + '</li></ul>';
                });
                //I use SweetAlert2 for this
                swal({
                    title: "Error " + jqXhr.status + ': ' + errorThrown,// this will output "Error 422: Unprocessable Entity"
                    html: errorsHtml,
                    width: 'auto',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Try again',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn',
                    cancelButtonClass: 'cancel-class',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnCancel: true,
                    type: 'error'
                }, function(isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $('#openModal').click();//this is when the form is in a modal
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Route -

```
Route::resource('/comments', 'CommentsController');
```

CommentsController@store -

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return response()->json(array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'There are incorect values in the form!',
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
            ), 422);
        }
        $this->throwValidationException(

            $request, $validator

        );
    }

    // Create Post
    $comment = new Comment;

    $comment->body = $request->body;
    $comment->user_name = auth()->user()->name;
    $comment->post_id = $request->post_id;
    $comment->profile_picture = auth()->user()->profile_picture;

    $comment->save();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']);
    //return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Comment Created');
```

Comment: Check error logs for actual error and where it is thrown

Comment: @Nikola please post your errors... And check your laravel or digging deeper server logs for that...